# GNU parallel with for loop function

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I would like to utilize all the cores (48) in AWS to run my job. I have 6 million lists to run and each job runs for a less than a sec [real    0m0.004s user   0m0.005s sys    0m0.000s].
My following execution uses all the cores but is NOT 100%.

```
gnu_parallel -a list.lst --load 100% --joblog process.log sh job_run.sh {} >>score.out
```

job_run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
i=$1
TMP_DIR=/home/ubuntu/test/$i
mkdir -p $TMP_DIR
cd $TMP_DIR/
m=`echo $i|awk -F '-' '{print $2}'`
n=`echo $i|awk -F '-' '{print $3}'`
cp /home/ubuntu/aligned/$m $TMP_DIR/
cp /home/ubuntu/aligned/$n $TMP_DIR/
printf '%s ' "$i"
/home/ubuntu/test/prog -s1 $m -s2 $n | grep 'GA'
cd $TMP_DIR/../
rm -rf $TMP_DIR
exit 0
```

Comment: The slow part is almost certainly `/home/ubuntu/test/prog`. How are we supposed to know how to speed that up?

Comment: @Barmer prog is pretty fast. it runs less than a sec and time shows [real 0m0.004s user 0m0.005s sys 0m0.000s]. What I'm asking is, how can I utilize the cores 100%.

Comment: Try removing `--load 100%` AFAIK that is meant as a throttle to potentially slow things down rather than a target to speed things up to. By default it will use all cores fully anyway. Get rid of the 2 `awk` processes too, and use `bash` Parameter Substitution instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is GNU Parallel's overhead: It takes 5-10 ms to start a job. So you will likely see GNU Parallel running at 100% on one core but the rest are idle.

But you can run multiple GNU Parallels:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Speeding-up-fast-jobs

So split the list into smaller chunks and run those in parallel:

```
cat list.lst | parallel --block 100k -q -I,, --pipe parallel --joblog process.log{#} sh job_run.sh {} >>score.out
```

This should run 48+1 GNU Parallels so it should use all your cores. Most of your cores will be used for overhead because your jobs are so fast.

If you are not using the `process.log`, then it can be done with less overhead:

```
perl -pe 's/^/sh job_run.sh /' list.lst | parallel --pipe --block 100k sh >>score.out
```

This will prepend each line with `sh job_run.sh` and give 100kb of lines to 48 `sh`s running in parallel.

Comment: perl script produces an error : 

sh: 0: Can't open sh job_run.sh abc-dec-fih-44hh-hhh-odjd.

Also specifying path to sh and list produces 
Unknown regexp modifier "/h" at -e line 1, at end of line

Comment: Sorry `--pipe` was missing. Edited.